# How to specify float precision in knex schema ?

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm having trouble defining float precision in a knex schema, i want it to be a float(10,6) in order to store lat/long location. Here's how im trying to declare it :

```
lat: {type: 'float(10,6)', nullable: false},
```

It fails at migrate because of the (10,6), so how is the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about this JSON approach since I only use the [Schema Builder](http://knexjs.org/#Schema) one.

It looks like (example `geostuff` table with `id`, `lat` and `lng` columns):

```
var knex = require('knex')({client:'sqlite3',connection:{filename: 'sample.sqlite3'}});

knex.schema.createTable('geostuff', function(table) {
  table.increments('id').primary();
  table.float('lat', 14, 10).notNullable();
  table.float('lng', 14, 10).notNullable();
}).then(function() {
  console.dir('table created');
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('table not created');
  console.dir(err);
});
```

Note the precision specifiers are not widely supported. PostgreSQL supports `float(precision)`, but SQLite3 (from the example), doesn't (better yet: does not care). Fortunately knex.js hides those idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 5):

To store geolocation I used a double precision data type, and for that my migration stays like that:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('route', table => {
        table.increments('id').primary()
        table.specificType('latitude', 'double precision').notNull()
        table.specificType('longitude', 'double precision').notNull()
    })
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('route')
};
```